# How to Log deleted files on Ubuntu?

Tags: file, logging, ubuntu-server

I want to track files that are deleted on my Ubuntu Server in a log file or a database. So if a file is deleted, I will know by who and when it was deleted.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `auditd` system (`sudo apt-get install auditd`). Something like this I think should enable deletion tracking for all files:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b32 -S unlink -S unlinkat -S rmdir -k deletion
```

I believe the logs should be showing up in `/var/log/audit`.

To learn more:

```
man auditctl
man audit.rules
```